# Sometimes I get a mistake in the compiler "Unable to create initial connections of pool."

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an application written in Spring, which works generally. However, there is such a problem that sometimes when compiling it throws me a mistake https://pastebin.com/kUjDFq16

It is a part of

```
  2017-10-03 22:24:10.195  WARN 300 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
2017-10-03 22:24:10.240 ERROR 300 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_144]

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at ...
```

This is the project https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services

This application works without any problems, but during some compilation it ejects this error during compilation.Sometimes I have to compile the application several times so that the error doesn't jump out, and sometimes I have to turn off the IDE and restart it.

EDIT: Now it doesn't compile at all and still makes a mistake.

Comment: This is not a compilation error, this probably appears during the build in tests. Apparently `url` is `null`, my guess is your application properties get rewritten somehow.

Comment: I do not run the application in tests.. Normally I run the application from the main  https://zapodaj.net/e0de66c5409b4.png.html.

Comment: No matter what you do or do not run, this is not a compilation error.